# Append element to Datatable header

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

What I'd like to do is add a radio button next to the **Search Bar** on my datatable to allow searching by just one column, **Store Number**.

I was referred to drawCallback but I don't believe this does what I expect it to do. All the answers I find seem to be appending elements to rows/cols in the datatable, but not the header itself.

The selector for this header is `#store-table_wrapper`.

```
   $('#store-table').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": [7, 8],
            "visible": false,
            "drawCallback": function() {
                $('<input type="radio" name="store-number-filter-selector" />').appendTo('#store-table_wrapper');
            }
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, getting your radio button displayed you're half-way through, the really challenging part is to disable default search bar, since you're unlikely to override its default behavior (to search through the entire table).

However, you may use your own, custom searchbar, like on the following **DEMO**:

```js
//define source data
const srcData = [
  {id: 1, name: 'apple', category: 'fruit'},
  {id: 2, name: 'raspberry', category: 'berry'},
  {id: 3, name: 'carrot', category: 'vegie'}
];
//define dataTable object
const dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  sDom: 't',
  data: srcData,
  columns: [
    {data: 'id', title: 'id'},
    {data: 'name', title: 'name'},
    {data: 'category', title: 'category'}
  ],
  //modify header nodes, by appending radios
  initComplete: function() {
    const table = this.api();
    [1,2].forEach(column => table.column(column).header().innerHTML += `<input type="radio" name="searchflag" value="${column}" class="searchflag"></input>`);
  }
});
//prevent sorting change upon radio click
$('input.searchflag').on('click', function(event) {
  //clear search upon choosing the other radio
  $('#searchfield').val('');
  dataTable.search('').columns().search('').draw();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
//searchbar keyup callback
$('#searchfield').on('keyup', function() {
  //grab checked radio button value or search the entire table by default
  let targetColumn = null;
  targetColumn = $('input.searchflag:checked').val();
  if(!targetColumn){
    dataTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
  }
  else {
    dataTable.column(targetColumn).search($(this).val()).draw();
  }
})
```

```css
input.searchflag {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <input id="searchfield"></input>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```